# cout pointer to array item is printing out different value than expected

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, cout

Why is it that my pointer value doesn't change when I print it to the console using this method:

```
int main()
{
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *p = array;
    p++;
    *p = 100;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << *array + i << ", ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when I print this to the console I get `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. What is the pointer actually pointing to in this instance? In this example `array[1]` should have the value of `100` but it doesn't change.

I also know that if I start the array at `5` for example, the counter will just print in order up from `5`. What is happening behind the scenes to cause this to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*array` resolves to the first element of the array. `*array + i` adds `i` to that element because due to operator precedence it is parsed as `(*array) + i`. So your loop prints `1 + 0`, `1 + 1`, etc.

If you want to print the elements of the array, you can do this:

```
for (auto e : array) cout << e << ", ";
```

If you want to use pointer arithmetic explicitly, the you will have to use parentheses in the right places:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     cout << *(array + i) << ", ";
```

Comment: Just a tiny note... no need to copy each element: 
for (const auto & e : array) cout << e << ", ";

Comment: @A.Fagrell In this case they are ints, so it is debatable whether using references helps.

Answer (score 2):

You're printing `array[0] + i` i.e. `1 + i` for `i` in [0, 5). No way has binary `+` operator higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than unary `*`. Use parentheses around `+` to form the right expression:

```
*(array + i) // or array[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cout << *(array + i) << ", ";
```